# SQL USE Statement equivalent in NHibernate c#

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Im trying to find a way to invoke the USE statement in NHibernate.

In SQL I can write something like this

```
USE MyDatabase;
SELECT * FROM Stuff

USE OtherDatabase;
SELECT * FROM OtherStuff
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior in NHibernate?

The second database is within the same authentication context (same server as well) hence there should be no need to switch the entire connectionstring.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I could do this

```
using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    session.CreateSQLQuery("USE OtherDatabase").ExecuteUpdate();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I will but have to wait a couple of days to mark my own answer as the solution.